# How do you pass a non-static function as a callback?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently working with Qt and a graphics engine and during the init of the QGLWidget instance I need to pass a few function pointers to my engine.

The function looking for callbacks is:

```
virtual void Buffer::CreateCustom( byte* getsize, byte* makecurrent)
```

Qt provides a [makeCurrent function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qglcontext.html#makeCurrent) however it is neither byte* nor static.

I could write a tiny wrapper function like so:

```
void _stdcall MakeCurrent(void)
{
    QGLContext::makeCurrent();
}
```

But its only meant to be called from within an instance of GLWidget. I tried to create a class member wrapper function like so:

```
void _stdcall LEWidget::leMakeCurrent(void)
{
    makeCurrent();
}
```

But you can only provide function pointers on static member functions. If I do that I get the following error:

*error C2352: 'QGLWidget::makeCurrent' : illegal call of non-static member function. A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.*

Comment: Dont know about Qt f/w..but have you looked at "boost::function" and "boost::bind" ?

Comment: See this question, I think it is pretty much what you want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381829/how-do-i-implement-a-callback-in-c

Comment: Well the way I see it, there has got to be a native way of doing it. I must be going about it the wrong way.

Comment: If Qt is expecting makeCurrent() to be "called from within an instance of GLWidget", you should follow this protocol, or the callback will most likely fail on execution.  You can do it using the link provided by nacho4d below.

Comment: Is it me or CreateCustom is declared really, really wrong? byte* is a function pointer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's what `std::function` exists for. You need to either change your interface to use `std::function`, get lucky and find some kind of `void* context` argument, or give up.

Answer (score -1):

This is because it is impossible to tell(from the compiler's POV) which `this` pointer should be pass into that function when that callback is called. If you really really want to pass in a pointer, you'll have to use assembly.