# Error on passing a non static function as parameter

Tags: c++, callback, arduino

I've read this question [How do you pass a non static function as callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373550/how-do-you-pass-a-non-static-function-as-a-callback)

But yet I'm still confused, (maybe because of my english knowledge =/ )

I'm trying to pass a non static function as a parameter of another function, using a global instanciated object pointer.

Please, consider the example:
**Classe_Indice.h**

```
#ifndef CLASSE_INDICE
#define CLASSE_INDICE

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Programas.h>

class Classe_Indice: public Programas
{

    public : int incrementaEvento();
             int incrementaFert();
             void setNumeroEvento(int numeroEvento);
             int getNumeroEvento();
             void setNumeroFert(int numeroFert);
             int getNumeroFert();

    private : int numeroEvento;
              int numeroFert;  

};



#endif
```

**Programas.h**

```
    #include <RTClib.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <TimeAlarms.h>

/*Biblioteca de Lista Encadeada*/
#include <LinkedList.h>

#include <Classe_Indice.h>
#include <Fertilizantes.h>
#include <Eventos.h>
#include <Agendamentos.h>
#include <RecuperaIrriga.h.> 
#include <RecuperaFerti.h>

class Programas: public Thread
        {
            public :   bool shouldRun();
                       void verificaProgramacao();


            private :  unsigned long tempo;
                       DateTime now;


        };


#endif
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Thread.h"
#include "ThreadController.h"
#include <Classe_Indice.h>
#include <Programas.h>

Classe_Indice *indice = new Classe_Indice();
ThreadController cpu;
Programas programacao = Programas();

int main()
{
    programacao.setInterval(200);
    programacao.onRun((indice->verificaProgramacao()));
    cpu.add(&programacao);
}
```

Note that in Classe_Indice.h I'm extending Programas... I've made this because I was getting the following error :error: 'class Classe_Indice' has no member named 'verificaProgramacao'. Then the problem changed to *invalid use of void expression*.. changing the synthax to programacao.onRun((*indice->verificaProgramacao())), I'll get : *error: void value not ignored as it ought to be*

I really dont know how to proceed with this. Sorry if this is a dup anyway.

Comment: What's the declaration/definition of `onRun`? It doesn't appear in your code. However `indice->verificaProgramacao()` already calls the function, it doesn't pass it as a parameter

Comment: read up on member function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT:::

1, try

```
     (*indice).verificaProgramacao();
```

2,

```
       programacao.onRun(some parameter)
```

,however, the function, 
             void  verificaProgramacao(); 
           is not a return type function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your intention. I guess you want `verificaProgramacao()` to be called/executed in another thread and you try to pass it as a parameter.
Actually, in the following way:

```
programacao.onRun((indice->verificaProgramacao()));
```

you are passing the result of the execution instead of the function/method itself. According to the declaration in the class `Programas` the function returns `void`, i.e. nothing:

```
void verificaProgramacao();
```

so you have an error.

I don't know the definition of the `Thread` class, but I suppose that you should either overload the `onRun` method (inherited from `Thread` I guess) in the `Programas` class and call `verificaProgramacao` in the reimplementation of `onRun`, or pass a pointer to `verificaProgramacao` to a constructor of `Classe_Indice` class object and then to a constructor of `Thread` if the class allows this (if there is an appropriate constructor).

To help you, I need more details, especially about the `Thread` class and your actual intention.

Comment: thank you so much for your effort. I'm trying to use verificaProgramacao as a callback function in onRun. In order to do so I need it to be a parameter of onRun's method, since verificaProgramacao is a non-static function, I'm passing it throught a pointer to object (which is called indice in this case). I'm using this library here : https://github.com/ivanseidel/ArduinoThread

Comment: onRun() calls a thread function to be executed when it should, this thread function is verificaProgramacao. I'm trying not to be redundant. Hope you understand this, feel free to ask.

Comment: I understand your idea, but: Why do you want to call a function/method defined within a class? Do you really want the callback function to operate on some instance of the `Programas` class? `verificaProgramacao` can be called for an object, while `onRun` has no access to the object. `verificaProgramacao` must be either defined outside a class or within a class as static component. In the latter case it cannot operate on instance variables of the class, only on static ones.

Comment: I'm falling in a huge problem. Can't see how I'm going to figure it out. I need whole of my thread functions ( few others similar to verificaProgramacao) to be able to "see" those variables int numeroFert and int numeroEvento (both declared among Classe_Indice.h). That's why I made whole thread functions as non-static. Since now you told me they should be static, I can't see how static methods would be able to see non-static variables. (I've tryed passing thread functions as static to onRun and compiler did not complain.

Comment: Problem fixed. I changed the methods to static and erased that Class_Indice.h , the variables which where declared within it now are global declared  int *numeroEvento and int *numeroFert, whenever I want to use them I pass them by memory adress &numeroEvento or &numeroFert. No compiling errors anymore, this does not mean that program will be executed properly but its already an enhancement. Thanks for the support !