# C++ Callback function, calling member variable inside static function

Tags: c++, static, callback

I've recently decided to start working with callback functions to make my life a bit easier. However, I'm having a bit of an issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class setCallback
{
public:
        setCallback() {}
        setCallback(std::function<int()> func) : callback(func) { }

        int call() { return callback(); }
private:
        std::function<int()> callback;
};

class callThis
{
public:
        callThis() : number(10) {}

        static int another()
        {
                return number;
        }
        int number;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
        std::shared_ptr<setCallback> caller;
        std::shared_ptr<callThis> funcholder;

        funcholder.reset(new callThis);
        caller.reset(new setCallback(funcholder->another));

        std::cout << caller->call() << "\n";

        std::cin.get();
}
```

As you can see from the code, I pull in the function from "callthis" into "setCallBack". This allows me to keep the function for later use, if needed. This works perfectly, however, if I attempt to load in a member variable from "callthis" into the static function, it obviously would not work (using a value does).

Is there a way around this? I would like to access the variable found within the class using the static function; optionally avoid using static functions when passing into the callback (but I assume this isn't possible due to the way callbacks work).

I've heard about wrapper classes but I'm not entirely sure how I would go about implementing it. Some insight would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Edit:

**Solved calling variables with callback functions, by B Sahu**

**Solved calling functions using callbacks without making the function being called static and keeping things reasonably uncoupled**

I researched how to call non-static functions using C++11; I thought it might be useful if anyone ends up having the same issues I do. This works on the same principles as  R Sahu proposed, however, using types and procedures found in  it ends up being a bit cleaner. Using std::bind(class::func, object) you can effectively gain the same results.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::function<void(void)> somefunc;

    Functionholder func;

    somefunc = std::bind(&Functionholder::say, &func);
}
```

Credit for this goes to: [This beautiful person](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3381854/2219465)

Which when used in a more complex example, having a class which holds the function to call, a caller class which will take the function and call it when required and a binder/state class (note, i'm using this for game UI), you can really get some reasonably neat and uncoupled code going:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Functionholder
{
public:
    void say() { std::cout << "hello!\n"; }
};

class CallbackHandler
{
public:
    CallbackHandler(){}
    CallbackHandler(std::function<void()> call) { callback = call; }

    void update() 
    { 
        //something happens to call this
        callback();
    }

    std::function<void()> callback;
};

class TheState
{
public:
    TheState()
    {
        hand = CallbackHandler(std::bind(&Functionholder::say, &func));
    }

    void update() { hand.update(); }

    Functionholder func;
    CallbackHandler hand;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    TheState state;
    state.update();

    std::function<void(void)> somefunc;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

If you have any improvements let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the ability to call the callback functions with user specified data. Then, use the data in the callback function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class setCallback
{
   public:
      setCallback() {}
      setCallback(std::function<int(void*)> func) : callback(func) { }

      int call(void* data) { return callback(data); }
   private:
      std::function<int(void*)> callback;
};

class callThis
{
   public:
      callThis() : number(10) {}

      static int another(void* data)
      {
         callThis* ptr = static_cast<callThis*>(data);
         return ptr->number;
      }
      int number;
};

// Fixed this line. You had
// int main(int argc, char** argv[])
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::shared_ptr<setCallback> caller;
   std::shared_ptr<callThis> funcholder;

   funcholder.reset(new callThis);
   caller.reset(new setCallback(callThis::another));

   std::cout << caller->call(funcholder.get()) << "\n";

   std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you. I am unable to check this out right now, however, this looks pretty solid. I notice that you pass in the "call this" object into the function used by "setcallback", what advantages does this method have over just sending the object, "callthis", into "setcallback" right from the start?

Comment: That's another approach which should also work. In that case, you have to store a pointer to the data in `setCallback`. You have to make a judgement call on where to put the data. If the `data` does not change from one invocation of `caller->call()` to the next invocation, you are better off putting it in `setCallback`. If it is likely to change, then you must provide it at the time of invocation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so essentially calling data using callbacks only really helps if the data will change at run time? I should probably post another question with this, but is there a way to call a non-static function from a static function? Would I use the same approach?

Comment: Hi, solved the issue with my solution in my post :) Thank you for your help!